# How to create table where each cell in column A is next to each cell in column B

Tags: excel

Good day, I'm not sure how to phrase the question I'm trying to ask so I'll try with an example.

I have 2 columns with a lot of data:

[image: before screenshot]

What I'm trying and failing to do is to "mix" the information but not the cells.
Similar to concatenate but not merging them into one cell, instead I want them in the same number of columns. Is there a name to this process?

So that the final result would look similar to this:

[image: result screenshot]

Comment: Looks like you want to sort your data:  highlight all the data, the choose Sort. Then sort by Column 2 first, then by Column 1.

Comment: Ah my bad, I guess I didn't phrase my question clearly.
The idea isnt in the sorting, its that I want each record from column A to be written next to each record from column B ..  close to N:M relationship if that makes sense.
Edit: so if I have 4 rows originally, the result table would be 16 rows.